# Filtering a Pivot Table in Google Scripts to exclude some values

Tags: pivot-table, google-sheets-api

I have managed to execute the Google API to create the pivot table dynamically and also to have the filtercriteria to work. Below is the code.

```
c = {
      11:{"visibleValues": ["value"]}
   };
```

However my challenge is now I want to be able to exclude some values instead of having to list all possible values. I tried hiddenValues, hiddenValue etc. Any idea what can help to exclude any values?

Comment: It's interesting, because the normal sheet filter (`BasicFilter`) only takes `hiddenValues`, and yet pivots only take `visibleValues`

Comment: This is still an issue 1 year and 11 months later. Google is a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only way to set a filter criteria is with "visibleValues": https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/PivotFilterCriteria.

I had the same issue and I finally collected all the visible values in an array, and then set the filter with

```
"criteria": {
   11: {"visibleValues": myArrayOfVisibleValues } 
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No shade at you Pulpo. But this is so pathetic from Google. I've been working with Google Products from a development point of view for about 2 years now and this honestly doesn't surprise me anymore. For anyone who is looking at the comment. This is still an issue a year later. FML.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no ad-hoc method specified for this, a workaround would be to:

1. get the list of all values
2. if `excluded_value` not in `full_list_of_values`
3. return `excluded_value`